The operation has timed out Exception when running python API script from C#
I have a Python file that runs a FastAPI API it works fine I run it from the Anaconda navigator. But when I run it with the help of c# after a few successful API calls it crashes and gives The operation has timed out exception. What could be the reason and how can I resolve it?
This is the code to start my Python API
 public static Process processAnaconda;
 public static (string text, bool status) RunAnacondaCmd(string fileName = "detection")
 {
     try
     {

         // Setting working directory and create process
         var workingDirectory = $@"{AppData.ProjectDirectory}\Voltas_api_image";
         processAnaconda = new Process
         {
             StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
             {
                 FileName = "cmd.exe",
                 RedirectStandardInput = true,
                 UseShellExecute = false,
                 RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                 WorkingDirectory = workingDirectory
             }
         };
         processAnaconda.Start();

         using (var sw = processAnaconda.StandardInput)
         {
             if (sw.BaseStream.CanWrite)
             {
                 // Vital to activate Anaconda
                 sw.WriteLine("C:\\Users\\Admin\\anaconda3\\Scripts\\activate.bat");
                 // Activate environment
                 sw.WriteLine("conda activate pytorch");
                 // running python script.
                 //ConsoleExtension.WriteWithColor($"File name for server is {fileName}", ConsoleColor.Green);
                 sw.WriteLine($"python {fileName}.py");
             }
         }


         ConsoleExtension.WriteWithColor("Api Started successfully", ConsoleColor.Yellow);
         return ("Api Running", true);

     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         Console.WriteLine($"Error while starting Detection API {ex.Message}");
         return ("Api not running", false);
     }
 }

I have tried to run the Python script in a new thread and also verified that the system resources are not exhausting.
